# Prolog list puzzle

Tags: list, prolog, logic, membership

I'm working on an assignment for my prolog course, but I'm stuck on how to handle some of the clues for the logic puzzles and would very much appreciate some hints/tricks/assistance:

Billy, Fernando, Steven, and Zachary all have an appointment at the doctor's. Unfortunately the doc's computer system broke down and s/he doesn't remember who had backpain, heartburn, hip pain, or shingles, and whether the appointments were at 9am, 10am, 11am or at 12. But fortunately, the following clues where found:

- of persons suffering from heartburn and billy, one has the 1100 appointment and the other the 0900 appointment.
- the heartburn patient has an appointment 2 hours after the hip pain patient.
- the shingles patient is either Billy or Fernando
- Zachary has an appointment sometime after the back pain patient.

So far I have this, but seeing how the zachary predicate results in an endless loop I'm fairly certain I have a wrong approach to it.

```
sublist( [], _ ).
sublist( [X|XS], [X|XSS] ) :- sublist( XS, XSS ).
sublist( [X|XS], [_|XSS] ) :- sublist( [X|XS], XSS ).

ziekte(X,Y,Z):-
    Appointments = [0900,1000,1100,1200],
    member(ziekte(Billy,_),Appointments),
    member(ziekte(Fernando,_),Appointments),
    member(ziekte(Steven,_),Appointments),
    member(ziekte(Zachary,_),Appointments),
    sublist([ziekte(Billy,_),ziekte(_,heartburn)],[0900,1100]),
    sublist([ziekte(Billy,shingles),ziekte(Fernando,shingles)],Appointments).

ziekte(_,back-pain,Y) :-
    ziekte(Zachary,_,X),
    X > Y.

ziekte(_,hip-pain,0900) :-
    ziekte(_,heartburn,1100).

ziekte(_,hip-pain,1000) :-
    ziekte(_,heartburn,1200).
```

I find myself having a hard time getting my head around Prolog so thank you for any trouble to be taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. First of all, Prolog atoms are always lowercase or quoted; `Billy` and `Fernando` etc. are variables, which is probably not what you intend them to be, so you will need to fix that.

Second, there is some confusing code here:

```
Appointments = [0900,1000,1100,1200],
member(ziekte(Billy,_),Appointments),
```

What you're saying here is, "I have a list of numbers, `[900,1000,1100,1200]`, and `ziekte(V1,_)` is in it." This is clearly false--there are no `ziekte/2` structures in this list.

I suspect you may be suffering from the most-common ailment of the beginning Prolog programmer: belief that Prolog relations "return" values. Do you think `ziekte(Billy,_)` is going to somehow cause `ziekte/3` to be called below, and somehow the third argument of the relation will appear in this location? It will not--there is no relationship between the structure `ziekte(_,_)` and the predicate `ziekte/3` defined below, and Prolog does not evaluate nested expressions like this at all.

What does `member(X, List)` do? It attempts to *unify* `X` with each value of `List`. Suppose you have a list that looks like `L = [appointment(zachary,back-pain,1100), appointment(steven,X,Y), appointment(Z,heartburn,900), ...]`. What does `member(appointment(billy,Ailment,900), L)` do? It tries to unify:

```
appointment(billy,Ailment,900) = appointment(zachary,back-pain,1100)
  fails
appointment(billy,Ailment,900) = appointment(steven,X,Y)
  fails
appointment(billy,Ailment,900) = appointment(Z,heartburn,900)
  succeeds with
    Ailment = heartburn
    Z = billy
```

If you find this surprising, you need to think harder about unification!

The reason you have infinite recursion is because your predicate `ziekte/3` calls itself. Look at the trace:

```
trace, ziekte(X,Y,Z).
   Call: (8) ziekte(_G4078, _G4079, _G4080) ? 
   Call: (9) _G4239=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Exit: (9) [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Call: (9) lists:member(ziekte(_G4232, _G4233), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Fail: (9) lists:member(ziekte(_G4232, _G4233), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Redo: (8) ziekte(_G4078, _G4079, _G4080) ? 
   Call: (9) ziekte(_G4230, _G4231, _G4232) ? 
   Call: (10) _G4242=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Exit: (10) [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Call: (10) lists:member(ziekte(_G4235, _G4236), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Fail: (10) lists:member(ziekte(_G4235, _G4236), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Redo: (9) ziekte(_G4230, _G4231, _G4232) ? 
   Call: (10) ziekte(_G4233, _G4234, _G4235) ? 
   Call: (11) _G4245=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Exit: (11) [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]=[900, 1000, 1100, 1200] ? 
   Call: (11) lists:member(ziekte(_G4238, _G4239), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Fail: (11) lists:member(ziekte(_G4238, _G4239), [900, 1000, 1100, 1200]) ? 
   Redo: (10) ziekte(_G4233, _G4234, _G4235) ?
```

What's happening here is this: you want to enter `ziekte(X,Y,Z)`. Prolog finds the first clause, the one with the head `ziekte(X,Y,Z)`. It immediately forms the list of appointment times. Then it checks to see if there is a `ziekte/2` structure in it. This fails. Prolog backtracks and tries the next clause: the one with the head `ziekte(_,back-pain,Y)`. The first expression in the body of this clause is `ziekte(Zachary,_,X)`. We recur: Prolog finds the first clause of `ziekte` and we are right back where we started.

Now you still have other problems. Notice you get a lot of singleton variable warnings. Begin treating these as fatal errors.

Your rule clauses look extremely strange to me. I don't know how they could possibly work, to be frank.

I think you're very lost here! I would strongly recommend you review the basics of Prolog. You can't fake it until you make it with Prolog, it really is completely different from everything else!

If I were you, I would begin by mapping out the domain with facts like `patient/1`, `time/1` and `ailment/1`. I made significant use of `select/3` in my solution, so I would review that. Also `plus/3`. Make sure you have a concrete understanding of the differences (and similarities) between structs--when evaluation will happen and when it will not. Then come back and try again!

**Edit:** Comments on the pastebin code.

The main problem with your pasted code is that you're trying to generate permutations with `sublist/2`, but what it does is give you ordered subsets. Your first pass through you have already generated a solution set, which fails, and then you spend the rest of your time in `sublist/2`.

Check this out:

```
?- ziekte(Y), sublist([Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4], Y).
Y = [backpain, heartburn, hippain, shingles],
Y1 = backpain,
Y2 = heartburn,
Y3 = hippain,
Y4 = shingles ;
false.
```

This only has one solution, so you're only really trying one permutation. By the time you hit the line with `member([billy,_,Tijd1], Opl)`, you've already set up `Opl = [[billy, backpain, 900], [fernando, heartburn, 1000], [steven, hippain, 1100], [zachary, shingles, 1200]]`. This would be fine if you were using something to permute the lists to generate different assignments, but the preceeding `sublist/2` calls have no more solutions, so there will not be any other assignments to X1..X4, Y1..Y4, Z1..Z4, so you're failing because the only solution you generated does not succeed.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got the general structure from a solution to a different problem (similiar structure question but about houses with pets).. I'll take your advice to heart and start from scratch on my own this time, thanks again.

Comment: Hey Daniel Lyons, in another attempt to grasp prolog I tried redoing the assignment(http://pasted.co/4d6de449) .. and while (I think) I'm getting closer to the solution (in great part thanks to you, thanks again) I now have an issue with having too many Billies coming over (I assume it has something to do with the first and third tip being about billy). If you can find the time to shine your light on it once more I'd be ever so gratefull.

Comment: I have edited my answer with some discussion of your new code.

Comment: You're my hero Daniel, even when I went searching for a better understanding of list permutations I ran into your answer(which was equally in depth might I add). Unfortunately after more trial and error I seem stuck at erroring, either my list permutation attempts are not working or the way I implemented the tip logic unification is erronous. When I trace I come across Opl lists with 5 elements in them.. was I wrong in assuming member([billy,_,Tijd1]) would unify with say  member([Patient1,shingles,_],Opl),select(Patient1,[billy,fernando],_),  ? Either way thank you for all the help given.

Comment: Well they're well ment, I atleast get the sense that I'm beginning to grasp the idea of unification now, so I'm very gratefull.  http://pasted.co/f9ac3f90 is where I'm at now, I find the trace worrysomely long however so I'm unsure if the permutation part is working correctly. On the other hand I just realised that in my first two member lines it can never unify billy with Tijd2.. I'm unsure how to get around this at this point though but if  (billy,heartburn,_) happens to be the correct answer then it'd make sense why my attempts are not working.

Comment: You are two characters from the correct solution! :) `select/3`'s third parameter is a list: `select(Tijd1,[0900,1100],[Tijd2])`

Comment: Clever use of `select/3` there, BTW!

Comment: [My solution](http://hastebin.com/dahofigezo.vhdl) is significantly longer. Yours requires a few more inferences to start with but doesn't produce additional bogus solutions, which is nice. Mine also seems to require more "Lips" but I'm not sure what that really measures. :) So all-in-all, a very good result I think!

Comment: Couldn't have done this without you in a gazillion years! Very happy with the correct solution (after the struggling), and more importantly with the gained insights! Can't thank you enough Daniel.. and thank you for the kind words, gives me courage to tackle the next assignment.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that, be sure and ask again if you get stuck! Always happy to help. :)